# Behaviour of std_logic's don't care in comparison

Tags: vhdl

I'm puzzled by the behaviour of `std_logic` type's *don't care* (`'-'`) value.

When comparing an `std_logic_vector` signal with an `std_logic_vector` constant that has one or more bits set to don't care does not seem to work like I would have expected, or counter-intuitively.

E.g. in the following example, I assumed that `do_something` would execute with values `"1101"` and `"1001"` in signal `s`, so the bit in index 2 would be ignored, as it's a don't care:

```
signal s : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
constant C : std_logic_vector(s'range) := "1-01";

if s = C then
    do_something;
end if;
```

but that does not seem to be case.

In my use case, I could keep the comparison simple with don't care values, as I don't have to check for the combinations with different values in the bit index 2.

How should the don't care values be used, and what is the actual behaviour? And even the purpose of having this value?

Comment: Your multiple questions demonstrate LRM usefulness, here IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.2.2 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values "*The value '–' is also called the don’t care value. This standard treats it in the same way as the other metalogical values except when it is furnished as an actual parameter to the STD_MATCH functions in the IEEE.NUMERIC_STD package or as an operand to a predefined matching relational operator (see 9.2.3). The STD_MATCH functions and the predefined matching relational operators use '–' to implement a “match all” or “wild card” matching.*" The entire subsection applies.

Comment: This subsection comes from IEEE Std 1076.3-1997 IEEE Standard VHDL Synthesis Packages 4.1 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values subsumed into IEEE Std 1076 in revision -2008. "‘U’, ‘X’, ‘W’, and ‘-’ are *metalogical values*; they define the behavior of the model itself rather than the behavior of the hardware being synthesized." 9.2.3 Relational operators includes matching relational operators added in -2008. Also see 16.8.2.4.4 Metalogical values in relational expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using the equality relation (=), the comparison will **always be false** when looking at the VHDL Languange reference manual ("LRM") (IEEE Standard 1076-2008) and the subchapter 16.8.2.4.4 *Metalogical values in relational expressions*:

> If one operand of an equality (=) relation is a one-dimensional array, and **one element of that one-dimensional array is a static metalogical value** (here it's my `constant C` and the element at index `2`), a synthesis tool shall interpret the entire equality relation as equivalent to the BOOLEAN value FALSE.

My original code will never execute the `do_something;` part:

```
signal s : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
constant C : std_logic_vector(s'range) := "1-01";

if s = C then -- Always FALSE!!!
    do_something;
end if;
```

The desired functionality from my question can be achieved with **STD_MATCH function**.

In the VHDL Languange reference manual, there's another subchapter 16.8.3 called *The STD_MATCH function and predefined matching relational operators*.

It says that the value is true when compared with a don't care value ('-'):

> The NUMERIC_STD package defines functions named STD_MATCH that –– provide wild card matching for the don't care value. Whenever the STD_MATCH function compares two actual parameters that are STD_ULOGIC values, it returns TRUE if and only if:
>
> - Both values are neither metalogical or high-impedance values and the values are the same, or
> - One value is '0' and the other is 'L', or
> - One value is '1' and the other is 'H', or
> - **At least one of the values is the don't care value ('-')**.

and as my values that I'm comparing, are std_logic_vectors (arrays) and not just single STD_LOGIC values, the STD_MATCH will return true if and only if:

> - The operands have the same length, and
> - STD_MATCH applied to each pair of matching elements returns TRUE.

So, I should have used `std_match` function (from numeric_std package) to get the behaviour that I expected:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

signal s : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
constant C : std_logic_vector(s'range) := "1-01";

if std_match(s, C) then
    do_something;
end if;
```